# Does postman API documentation support tryout feature similar as swagger

Tags: postman, swagger, rspec-api-documentation

Does postman API documentation support tryout feature similar as swagger and suggest best tool for the API documentation

Answer (score 0):

Once you publish your documentation, on the right side you'll see the option "Run in Postman". Click on that option and you'll be able to run those requests in postman.

For reference, you can try this [API documentation](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/631643/JsLs/)